# Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder Error Handling

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

When a Kinesis stream consumer encounters an error and an exception is thrown in a method annotated with `@StreamListener`, how can the binding be configured so that the message is re-queued or sent to a DLQ? I see this level of support for Rabbit and Kafka in Spring Cloud Stream, but I'm not seeing it for the Kinesis binding. What is the recommended approach for handling errors in a Kinesis stream processor? How is it done via configuration and/or code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Kinesis Binder implementation is fully based on the Spring Cloud Stream Core and just re-uses its generic approach for error handling: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling

So, what you need is just some `@ServiceActivator` for particular destination error channel and do whatever you need with a failed record.

There is no DLQ/DLX/DLT functionality in AWS Kinesis at all, so I don't see reason to abuse it purpose and introduce something artificial into Kinesis Binder.

Comment: The documentation states: "For each input binding, Spring Cloud Stream creates a dedicated error channel with the following semantics <destinationName>.errors." We provision our streams in our CI/CD pipeline, and I don't see any .errors Kinesis streams provisioned in the AWS console. We have the property ```spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.autoCreateStream=false```, so is this why there are no automatically provisoned .errors streams?

Comment: No, the story is about internal `MessageChannel`. As I said you: there is no DLQ, so no AWS provisioning at all. That is your responsibility to reach that goal in the target project.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. So, just to be sure I understand how this works, if I provision a Kinesis stream named ```xyz.processing```, then I also need to provision a stream named ```xyz.processing.errors```. With those two streams in place, when my ```@StreamListener``` method throws an exception, then the method annotated with ```@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = xyz.processing.errors)``` should be invoked. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Well, you don't  the `xyz.processing.errors` stream in the Kinesis. The channel is going to be there anyway.

Comment: Artem, do you have a sample project that demonstrates this error processing capability via the ```@ServiceActivator```? It is not working for me. It seems simple enough, but I must be missing something.

Comment: I was missing the group name as part of the inputChannel name. That's why I couldn't get it to work. One more question for you, Artem. Is there a programmatic way to set the consumer group name that a message should be delivered to? In the case of a microservice that fails processing of a message from Kinesis, I want to have a solution where I can re-queue the message back to the original stream it was placed on, but I only want it to be delivered to the consumer group for the microservice that failed, not all consumer groups as specified via properties. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, that's the wrong way to treat consumer group abstraction. It is fully not related to the producer side. I can imagine the way you send a record back to the stream with some additional info about consumer group. On the consumer side you can do a *filtering* logic to skip a record with not-our-consumer-group-info. But that's fully unstable solution: the consumer group is there for a reason to not re-read the same record from the stream. It might be changed for some reason, so your re-queued record won't be consumer again.

Comment: Well, my reasoning for this is that if I re-send the message on the original Kinesis stream, I don't want every single consumer to re-process the message, only the one that failed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand your goal, but we need to take a look at this from different angle and keep in mind that this consumer may be lost in between, so re-queued won't be re-consumed again. You need to think about the logic which is independent from any consumer. That's really an anti-pattern to tie a produce with particular consumer.

Comment: I see. Well, do you have any recommendations for best practices on how to ensure that the message which now can't be re-read from the Kinesis stream can eventually be processed again? Is this simply a detail left to each individual microservice that doesn't rely on Kinesis (since we can't requeue, use DLQ, etc.)? The overall goal is to ensure that, if there is any exception that causes a microservice to not process a message successfully, we can re-process that same message at some future point, ensuring that the system remains eventually consistent.

Comment: You can apply *retry* pattern in the consumer logic. So, if an exception is there, you don't need to re-send a record back to the stream: you just retry until intermittent state disappears. In addition to this you can rely on the *manual* ack for checkpoint. And with this approach you won't pull more records from the stream - you are blocked to retry and don't let a control come back to the shard iterator request.

Comment: By retry pattern, are you specifically referring to Spring Retry? Also, I didn't see any properties in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc where I can configure any manual ack capabilities with Kinesis streams like I see for Kafka streams in https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options_2 (e.g., the consumer property ackEachRecord). For Kinesis stream processing, how can I do manual ack of the Kinesis messages?

Comment: See `checkpointMode`: 

`The mode in which checkpoints are updated. If record, checkpoints occur after each record is processed (but this option is only effective if listenerMode is set to record). If batch, checkpoints occur after each batch of records is processed. If manual, checkpoints occur on demand via the Checkpointer callback. If periodic, checkpoints occurs at specified time interval (from interval property in checkpoint configuration)`

Comment: OK, your explanations are really helping me better understand how to think through this. So, as long as my microservice keeps trying to process the message (and I'm still not clear if you are talking about Spring Retry here or not) AND I am using a manual checkpointMode, then further message processing is blocked as more records won't be pulled from the stream. In the event my microservice fails, when it is eventually restarted, record processing will continue from the last checkpoint. If this understanding is correct, then how does this approach work with more than one microservice running?

Comment: In other words, if one microservice is failing while another in the same consumer group is not failing, then will the one that is failing and manually acknowledging records block the other microservice from processing, since the checkpoint is still in limbo?

Comment: Right. I talk about Spring Retry and what you can use on the `@ServiceActivator` with the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-advice

Comment: Well, if we talk about a *consumer group*, then it is obvious that only one microservice instance is going to pull records from a single shard. That is a real point of the consumer group: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#consumer-groups

Comment: I have a solution working using the ```@Retryable``` and ```@ServiceActivator``` annotations in addition to setting the Kinesis consumer property ```checkpointMode``` to ```manual```. With this configuration in place, do I also need to set the Kinesis consumer property ```listenerMode``` to ```record``` to always ensure I only ever process and checkpoint one record at a time?

Comment: For example, I wouldn't ever want to process a batch of records (10 for example) and have the first nine process successfully and the last one fail. Using the solution I currently have, the checkpointMode wouldn't accurately reflect the status of the records I processed, and I'd end up reprocessing the first nine records again (that originally processed just fine) and the one that failed.